# Accessing Typescript-ES5 or Node Error message

Tags: java, spring, typescript

I have an error handler. I don't know if it is Node or Typescript-ES5 Error object. When I inspect in the console, I have the following

```
{…}
error: Object { message: "message that I want to get" }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/someEnpointUrl: 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
url: "http://localhost:4200/someEnpointUrl"
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Inspecting the Error object the only information I can get is error.name and error.message, but in my case I get
error.message = "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/someEnpointUrl: 400 Bad Request"
and
error.name = HttpErrorResponse

On the back-end, the error is coming from

throw new ControllerException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "message that I want to get");

How can I get the error message on the front end (error: Object { message: "message that I want to get" }) The editor cannot get this object property?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Aren't you able to access the error message in js?

Comment: yes I cannot access the error message in js

Comment: And what does a `console.log(e)` say? Is the status `400` or `500`?

Comment: The status is 400

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I created a custom error

```
export class ExtendedError extends Error{

  public error!: { message: string }
  constructor(m: string) {
    super(m);
  }
}
```

and can get error.error.message
The discussion is closed